# How to copy an element's height to another element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, outerheight

I have a div that has **padding only** and i have another div without any css attribute.
I want to give the same height to both divs using `outerHeight`.

This is my test, this works but not perfectly:
http://jsfiddle.net/A2bNm/6/

```
$("#container").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#top").animate({ 'padding' : 70 }, "slow");
        $("#bottom").animate({'height':($("#top").outerHeight())}, "slow");

    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $("#top").animate({ 'padding' : 20}, "slow");
        $("#bottom").animate({'height':($("#top").outerHeight())}, "slow");
});
```

Can help? Thank you and sorry for my bad english! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to your divs with their current name `this` and with the other's name `.closest('div)` or `.siblings('div')`.

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Also, perhaps store the required height as an independent variable, so it's not based on the #top's current value (which changes).

Comment: I tried to referring my divs with `this`, but doesn't work! Can you give a jsfiddle example? Thanks!

Comment: I was referring to this http://jsfiddle.net/A2bNm/7/ as a usage, without the actual full implementation. note that I'm selecting the children of the container so that $(this) refers to each div.

Comment: Thank you veru much! but in the div **#top** and **#bottom** i have other divs, so if i use `$(this)` this refers to all divs. I tried to change `this` to id name, but doesn't work.

Comment: What i want to do is to clone the div #top wrapper only. I tried with `.clone` but this clone the whole div (with internal contents).

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your issue without some examples. maybe raise another question?